# Remove duplicates and only keep the ones with a specific word succeeding it

Tags: linux, text-processing, scripting

I am new to bash scripting and would like to change a minor code to the current script I have.

I have a file containing dates and the words "active" or "not active" succeeding the date, similar to the one below:

```
2019-02-17 not active
2019-02-18 active
2019-02-19 not active
2019-02-19 not active
2019-02-19 active
2019-02-19 not active
2019-02-19 not active
2019-02-19 active
2019-02-20 active
2019-02-21 not active
2019-02-22 not active
```

I want to remove every duplicate of "2019-02-19 not active" while keeping one copy of "2019-02-19 active". Would appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, you want to keep only one line per day, and if there are `avtive` and `not active` on one day, keep the `active`?

Comment: @Philippos Hi, actually the file containing the data is actually captured off from a log file, which that log file is being generated by a software. The only reason being why there are multiple occurrences at certain times is because the software had been rebooted during those dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `uniq`, you can do

```
 sort file | uniq -w 10
```

Option `-w` limits the comparison to 10 chars, so each date will only survive once. The sorting makes `active` appear first, so it will be the one to stay.

If future readers of this question happen to be on a system without GNU `uniq`, you can use `sed`, for example. The classical way to remove duplicate lines is

```
sed '$!N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;D'
```

The `N;P;D` pattern always keeps two lines in the pattern space, but only prints the first one, if the second is not the same. We can vary this script to only check for duplicates in the date part:

```
sed '$!N;/^\([^ ]*\) .*\n\1/!P;D'
```

Now we only have to take care to prefer `active` lines:

```
sed '$!N;/^\([^ ]*\) .*\n\1/!P;//s/\(.*\)\(\n\).*not.*/\2\1/;D'
```

The first part remains the same: Only print lines after the date changed (or on the last line). But if the date is the same (the empty pattern in the address `//` means to repeat the last pattern), usually the second line is preserved. But if this second line has `not` in it, we should better keep the first line (`active` or `not active`), so the `s` command makes the first line second (after an empty line, which will get removed by the `D` anyhow).

I admit this is less elegant than the GNU version, but at least it stays a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be it! Didn't know it was this simple!

Answer (score 0):

A unique sort will do this.

```
$ sort -u input.txt
2019-02-17 not active
2019-02-18 active
2019-02-19 active
2019-02-19 not active
2019-02-20 active
2019-02-21 not active
2019-02-22 not active
```

BTW, `sort input.txt | uniq` does the same thing, and `uniq` has a `-f` option for skipping fields when determining uniqueness, `-d` and `-D` options if you want to print the non-unique lines instead of only the unique ones.

---

Alternatively, if you want only one output line per date, and for any "active" entry to take precedence over "non active" (or other) entries:

```
perl -lane '
  $date=shift @F;
  $day{$date} = join(" ",@F) unless ($day{$date} eq "active");
  END {print $_ . " " . $day{$_} for (sort keys %day)}' input.txt
2019-02-17 not active
2019-02-18 active
2019-02-19 active
2019-02-20 active
2019-02-21 not active
2019-02-22 not active
```

This builds a hash (`%day`) with the dates as the keys, and the remaining fields as the values.   The current or last-seen value for any given day will replace an earlier-seen value **unless** the value for any given day, is already "active".  In that case, the day's value will not be replaced.

When all the input has been read, the %day hash is sorted and printed.

This is more generically useful and re-usable than relying on the sort order of the second field.  e.g, if you wanted "zzzzz" to take precedence rather than "action".  Also useful if the 2nd field might contain something that sorted before "action" (e.g. a number)

Comment: I understand that `2019-02-19 not active` should completely be removed

Comment: "remove every duplicate" doesn't mean the same thing as "remove every occurrence" -- it's "remove all but the first" vs "remove all".   the OP can clarify if they mean something other than what they wrote.

Comment: In this case it would be nonsense to distinguise between active and not active. I think, "duplicate" only refers to the first field, the date. It's often neccessary not only to read what they wrote, but to sense what they meant.

Comment: good for you. feel free to write your own answer.  Until the OP clarifies, I'm going to assume he's writing in standard English where using the phrase "remove every duplicate" gives the exact sense of what they mean.

Comment: Hello, @cas! Thanks for providing a solution. The alternate solution seems to be what I'll be using, however it does not print out cases wherein there are multiple occurrences of a date "not active" and not one "active", or vice versa. It would skip out the date instead. By removing duplicate, I simply want to remove multiple occurrences of a date, and only keep the one that is "active". If there are no "active" for that date but still has multiple occurrences of the date, then I would like to keep one date with "no active". I am sorry for how I write in English, which may have been confusing.

Comment: I don't get the difference between that and what the perl one-liner does.  It prints exactly one line per date. If a date has multiple lines, it will print "active" if that line exists (no matter how many "not active" lines may also exist), otherwise it will print the last one seen (i.e. "not active").